# How to get the first character of a row and group it with the first character of other rows and create a column from that

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to write an sql where in the table the first character of a row be grouped with different first letters of some rows and then that group is named.let's say that is a list of students. and I want students whose first name start with a particular letter to be put in a specific group. If there first name starts with A,B or C then they are put in a group and that group will be named 'Junior'; if their first name starts with D, E or F then they are put in a group that will be named 'Senior'.  e.g.

```
KATE
JANE
MARY
NICOLE
ROBIN

A-C = Junior
D-F = Senior
G-I = Teacher
```

Comment: It's not clear what's your requirement. Please show the desired output and your table data.

Comment: let's say that is a list of students. and I want students whose first name start with a particular letter to be put in a specific group. If there first name starts with A,B or C then they are put in a group and that group will be named 'Junior'; if their first name starts with D, E or F then they are put in a group that will be named 'Senior'.

Comment: But the sample data you gave all start after `J`, so none would be in either of the 3 categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a group by clause, what you are asking is a simple `DECODE` or `CASE` expression.

Demo:

```
with data as
(
select 'ANGELINA' name from dual union all
select 'DAVID' from dual union all
select 'IAN' from dual union all 
select 'NICOLE' from dual union all
select 'ROBIN' from dual

)
-- Your query starts here
select name, 
       case 
         when substr(name, 1, 1) in ('A','B','C')
         then 'Junior'
         when substr(name, 1, 1) in ('D','E','F')
         then 'Senior'
         when substr(name, 1, 1) in ('G','H','I')
         then 'Teacher'
       end as letter 
from data;

NAME     LETTER 
-------- -------
ANGELINA Junior 
DAVID    Senior 
IAN      Teacher
NICOLE          
ROBIN
```

The with data clause is only to build the sample data as you have not provided any. In your actual query, use your table name instead of data. Remove everything before the comment "-- Your query starts here".